# apt-get is stuck trying to remove an unremovable package

Tags: apt, package-management

Some time ago I installed [jitsi-meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet). It did not work so I tried to remove it, but got an error:

```
Removing jitsi-meet-web-config (1.0.2301-1) ...
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-web-config (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jitsi-meet-web-config
```

I [opened an issue in jitsi](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/2112)  but they said they are not going to fix it at the moment.

Now, whenever I try to install a new package, even if it is not related to jitsi at all, the installation fails with the same error. I cannot install any new package!

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/jitsi-meet-web-config.postrm` remove the lines

```
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/apache2" ]; then
    invoke-rc.d apache2 reload
fi
```